# Java Reading big file java heap space

Tags: java, heap-memory

I have written this code:

```
try(BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\big50m.txt"));){
              String line;
              StringTokenizer st;

              while ((line = file.readLine()) != null){
                  st  = new StringTokenizer(line); // Separation of integers of the file line
                  while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                       numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken())); //Converting and adding to the list of numbers
                  }

          }
          catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println("Can't read the file...");

          }
```

the big50m file has 50.000.000 integers and i get this runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:596)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:367)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:370)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at unsortedfilesapp.UnsortedFilesApp.main(UnsortedFilesApp.java:37)
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

I think the problem is the string variable named `line`. Can you tell me how
to fix it ? Because i want fast reading i use StringTokenizer.

Comment: Have you looked at the file structure?

Comment: Yes..  for example :   100 5  55 75  13 ....   integer1 onespace integer2 ...

Comment: Do the file have any \n's in it?

Comment: Hmm, no, all numbers are in the same line...

Comment: Well that could be your problem. You are trying to read all 50,000,000 numbers at once.

Comment: what is your file size by the way

Comment: 50.000.000 integers, and file size is 203 MB

Comment: You could use Scanner but speed may be an issue. It's worth trying though.

Comment: No i tried it, but is too slow

Comment: @LeAdErQ Why don't you try increasing your max heap size

Comment: @LeAdErQ can you check your heap size by typing "java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize"

Comment: I tried it , and doesn't work.

Comment: @Junbang Huang , where i will write this command ??

Comment: command line?..

Comment: @LeAdErQ command line tool

Comment: I suggest you change the file structure. Create a program that uses scanner to make lines of 100 or something in a new file. Then use that file for your program.

Comment: @LeAdErQ if you are using IDE, you can see your heap size from the screen directly. like this one (https://dzone.com/articles/show-heap-status-eclipse)

Comment: @Sedrick Jefferson this is not on my hand...

Comment: @LeAdErQ can you share your way to increase the heap size?

Comment: Did u try setting a higher value like 512mb? `java -Xmx512m <Your Class Name>`

Comment: @JunbangHuang i use NetBeans.

Comment: @Arun, i tried it, but no result.. i think that the problem is the string named  "line"

Comment: @LeAdErQ no the problem is file.readLine() it will try to read to the first newline, and since there aren't any it will read the whole file into a String.

Comment: For smaller input ( 5 million integers) it works...

Comment: @LeAdErQ can you share the file and code so that I can test it out on my machine. I still think it is a heap size problem, shouldn't be that complicated.

Comment: File of integers : https://ufile.io/263111

Answer (score 1):

Create a `BufferedReader` from the file and `read()` char by char. Put digit char into a `String`, then `Integer.parseInt()`, skip any non-digit char and continue parsing on the the next digit, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

here is an version that minimize the memory usage. No byte to char conversion. No String operations. But in this version it does not handle negative numbers.

```
    public static void main(final String[]a) {
        final Set<Integer> number = new HashSet<>();
        int v = 0;
        boolean use = false;
        int c;
        // Input stream avoid char conversion
        try(InputStream s = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\big50m.txt")) {
            // No allocation in the loop
            do {
                if((c = s.read()) == -1) break;
                if(c>='0' && c<='9') { v = v * 10 + c-'0'; use =     true; continue; }
                if(use) number.add(v);
                use = false;
                v = 0;
            } while(true);
            if(use) number.add(v);
        } catch(final Exception e){ System.out.println("Can't read the file..."); }
    }
```

Comment: Hi SkateScout,  i saw that you used Set, but i don't want set, i want to add  same values..

Comment: Hi, i want an working sample since your query did not contain any information about number it can be an Collection or Some self defined class. But it does not affect the optimization.

Answer (score 0):

The readLine() method reads the whole line at once thus eating up a lot of memory. This is highly inefficient and does not scale to an arbitrary big file.

You can use a [StreamTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html)

like this:

```
StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new FileReader("bigfile.txt"));
tokenizer.parseNumbers(); // default behaviour
while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
    if (tokenizer.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
        numbers.add((int)Math.round(tokenizer.nval));
    }
}
```

I have not tested this code but it gives you the general idea.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you are storing the numbers in a List. Unless this is just a toy program, increasing the heap space is no real solution. Memory is an expensive and limited resource. In real problems you will have to read a reasonable amount of data into memory, processes it and proceed until the data is exhausted. The JVM can access a limited amount of memory at once so reading all the numbers into a List does not scale. If this is a real world problem you should consider using cache techniques and process the numbers in parts. I estimate that your approach is using 500MB+ of memory.

Answer (score 0):

On Running the program with -Xmx2048m, the provided snippet worked (with some adjustments: declared numbers as List numbers = new ArrayList<>(50000000); )

Comment: i don't know the number of integers

Answer (score 0):

Since all numbers are within one line, the `BufferedReader` approach does not work or scale well. The complete file will be read into memory. Therefore the streaming approach (e.g. from @whbogado) is indeed the way to go.

```
StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new FileReader("bigfile.txt"));
tokenizer.parseNumbers(); // default behaviour
while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
    if (tokenizer.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
        numbers.add((int)Math.round(tokenizer.nval));
    }
}
```

As you are writing, that you are getting a **heap space error** as well, I assume, that it is not a problem with the streaming anymore. Unfortunately you are storing all values within a List. I think that is the problem now. You say in a comment, that you do not know the actual count of numbers. Hence you should avoid to store those in a list and do here as well some kind of streaming.

For all who are interested, here is my little testcode (java 8) that does **produce a testfile** of the needed size `USED_INT_VALUES`. I limited it for now to 5 000 000 integers. As you can see running it, the memory increases steadily while reading through the file. The only place that holds that much memory is the **numbers** `List`.

Be aware that initializing an `ArrayList` with an **initial capacity** does **not** allocate the memory the stored objects need, in your case your `Integers`.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StreamTokenizer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class TestBigFiles {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        heapStatistics("program start");
        final int USED_INT_VALUES = 5000000;
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("testdata_big_50m", ".txt");
        System.out.println("using file " + tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
        tempFile.deleteOnExit();

        Random rand = new Random();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tempFile);
        rand.ints(USED_INT_VALUES).forEach(i -> {
            try {
                writer.write(i + " ");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestBigFiles.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });
        writer.close();
        heapStatistics("large file generated - size=" + tempFile.length() + "Bytes");
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(USED_INT_VALUES);

        heapStatistics("large array allocated (to avoid array copy)");

        int c = 0;
        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(tempFile);) {
            StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(fileReader);

            while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
                if (tokenizer.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
                    numbers.add((int) tokenizer.nval);
                    c++;
                }
                if (c % 100000 == 0) {
                    heapStatistics("within loop count " + c);
                }
            }
        }

        heapStatistics("large file parsed nummer list size is " + numbers.size());
    }

    private static void heapStatistics(String message) {
        int MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
        //clean up unused stuff
        System.gc();
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        System.out.println("##### " + message + " #####");

        System.out.println("Used Memory:" + (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / MEGABYTE + "MB"
                + " Free Memory:" + runtime.freeMemory() / MEGABYTE + "MB"
                + " Total Memory:" + runtime.totalMemory() / MEGABYTE + "MB"
                + " Max Memory:" + runtime.maxMemory() / MEGABYTE + "MB");
    }
}
```